# How to convert HOC to react component syntax for apollo?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, next.js

Could anyone help me understand how I can abstract away apollo graphQL logic to convert between using apollo with HOC versus using the more modern `<Query>({data, loading})=>(<MyComponent data={data} loading={loading}/>)</Query>` syntax? Or if I can't do that, how you can use HOCs in a sub component that is not the whole page itself? I'm using `next-apollo-appsync` to handle all of my graphQL issues:

```
import { withAppSyncData } from "next-apollo-appsync";
import AppSyncConfig from "./aws-exports";

const config = {
  url: AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
  region: AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_region,
  auth: {
    type: AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
    apiKey: AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_apiKey
  }
};

export default withAppSyncData(config);
```

Once I create a withData function with my appsync settings, I use the withData function to create a TodosWithData function.

```
import withData from "../../lib/withData";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";

const query = gql`
  query listTodos {
    listTodos {
      items {
        id
        name
        completed
      }
    }
  }
`;

const TodosWithData = MyComponent =>
  withData(
    graphql(query, {
      options: {
        fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network"
      },
      props: props => ({ todos: props.data.listTodos ? props.data.listTodos.items : [] })
    })(MyComponent)
  );

export default TodosWithData;
```

This function will take a react component as an input and will return apollo wrapped around the component, and we'll have access to the data under `this.props.data`, just like we'd expect. The weird thing is that I can get this dumb component below to work, but only if it is on the page level- it does not work if I move it to a component that I load from a page.

```
import React from "react";
import TodosQuery from "../graphql/components/todos";

class Todos extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props); //We have access to the apollo payload
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Static Text</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//This is what injects apollo payload into the Todos dumb-component.
export default TodosQuery(Todos);
```

Here is a [working repo](https://github.com/CaptainChemist/next-appsync-example) for reference. The actual error I get is `Cannot read property 'apollo' of undefined`

Comment: I believe the `withData` HOC must be applied to the page level (your `App` component in `src/index.js`) because it calls `getInitialProps`, which can only be used in pages, not children components.

Comment: Using `withData` allowed me to move the Todos into a different file, so that's a great start!  Any idea if you can use `<Query>` syntax as long as you keep `withData` on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, and using the `<Query>` syntax:

In `src/index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import withData from "../lib/withData";
import TodosWithData from "../graphql/components/todos";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("props: ", this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <TodosWithData />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withData(App);
```

In `src/graphql/components/todos.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const query = gql`
  query listTodos {
    listTodos {
      items {
        id
        name
        completed
      }
    }
  }
`;

const TodosWithData = () => (
  <Query query={query} fetchPolicy="cache-and-network">
    {({ loading, error, data: { listTodos } }) => {
      if (error) return <div>Error loading todos</div>
      if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {listTodos.items.map(todo => (
               <li key={todo.id}>{`${todo.name}${todo.completed ? " - DONE" : ""}`}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    }}
  </Query>
);

export default TodosWithData;
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could import the query from an outside file, or pass it as a prop, it doesn't have to be defined in the component file.

Comment: Also, not sure if your query returns a single list of several items, or several lists of several items. If it's the second option, then you would need an outer `.map` as well, to iterate over lists before you iterate over items ;)

Comment: I tried your example and it definitely makes sense but I get this error: `Error: GraphQL error: Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'listTodos' in type 'Query' is undefined @ 'listTodos'` I made a new branch with the mapping part commented out. I can get it to work the original way but not with the component syntax. Maybe an `next-apollo-appsync` issue? It's a fork of `next-apollo` https://github.com/CaptainChemist/next-appsync-example/tree/newsyntax

Comment: @Coherent this looks like a plain GraphQL error. Did you validate your query with a tool like GraphiQL or GraphQL Playground? Could you show me your GraphQL schema? Hard to give you an accurate answer without that info. Thanks.

Comment: You were totally right, this was a user error on my end for not setting up appsync properly. That repo above has been updated to work using the component syntax. Thanks so much Jaxx!!